# How to put Number List into Compobox Value list in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have a field which has numeric multiValues (5,10,15,20). 
I would like to put that values into a ComboBox but ı get this error :( 
I tried to get values Array or Vector They did not work :( I could not find any other way the solve it.

```
<xp:comboBox id="RatesList">
<xp:selectItems>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var prmDb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), sessionScope.prm_db_Path); 
var prmView:NotesView = prmDb.getView("(viewPrm)");
var prmColl:NotesViewEntryCollection = prmView.getAllEntries();
if (prmColl.getCount()>0)
{
    var prmEntry:NotesViewEntry = prmColl.getFirstEntry();
    var prmDoc: NotesDocument = prmEntry.getDocument();
    //var rVal:Array = new Array(prmDoc.getItemValue("prmRates"));
    var rList:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector(prmDoc.getItemValue("Rates"));
    //for (var i=0; i<rVal.length; i++)
    //{
        //  rList.addElement(rVal[i]);
    //}
    return rList;
}}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:selectItems>
</xp:comboBox>
```

[image: Error Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your numbers to strings:

```
        var rates = prmDoc.getItemValue('Rates');
        var items = [];
        for (var i=0; i < rates.length; i++) {
            items.push(rates[i].toString());
        }
        return items;
```

Comment: I did it as you said then I have checked that value was saved as Numeric.
That is what exacly I wanted it to be :)

Thank you.